# Google Cloud Platform project with the Gmail API: Create token for Desktop Application

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, credentials

Scope: I want to access my Gmail via python and the Gmail API on Raspbery pi /Raspian or Windows 10.

Following the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) from Google I created a project and enabled the Gmail API, Authorization credentials for a desktop application according to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id) for Desktop app, downloaded it and renamed it to `credentials.json` when running quickstart.py I get as expected:

`>>> # get the Gmail API service`

`... service = gmail_authenticate()`

`Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A34551%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F&state=[xxx]&access_type=offline`

When opening the URL in the browser:
[image]

I follow the link to *unsafe*:

[image]

and get the link to localhost:

`http://localhost:34551/?state=[XXX]&code=[XXX]&scope=https://mail.google.com/`
[image]

Question:
How can I get the app authorized / get the `client_secret.json`, etc?

Comment: Are you running an HTTP server to handle the redirect? Edit your question to show your code and provide the English translations for your images.

Comment: Yes IIS. But xampp did finally work

Answer (score 1):

Installing xampp solved the issue.
The windows IIS did not work in this case